# MVVM data templates and non-direct data mapping

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I've been using mvvm to develop a RIA service sl4 app and i seem to be missing something.

The MVVM and databinding works nice when your data comes in the expected format for editing or when your data objects "fits the view" (grids, lists, etc). But what happens when your data doesn't really map directly?

My example

Lets say i have a product table, this defines the product its price and options. And i have a subscribed product table that will link the product and client and also have data on when the subscription ends etc...

So when i started working on my view for a "shopping list" i did this:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ShopList" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding ModuleName}" />
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding DateStart, Converter={StaticResource gridDateFormatter}}" />
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding DateEnd, Converter={StaticResource gridDateFormatter}}" />
                <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox MaskedText="{Binding UnitsToBuy}" />
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding UnitStep}" />
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding TotalPrice}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

So i thought well I'm gonna bind ItemsSource with a Observable collection on my ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
```

But now i have a problem, the UnitsToBuy is something not in the Product, and doesn't belong on the product. I'm strugling on how to find a clean way to deal with these kinds of scenario. Do assume i can have any number of items in that list.

Thanks.

Comment: Is UnitsToBuy part of another Model object or is it all by itself? I guess my question is whether or not you're trying to merge together two Models.

Comment: @avanek well it will be used in another model, lets say the SubscribedProduct model/table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're asking boils down to the fact that the view needs a viewmodel with more properties, not a simple model. Why not have something like this. Obviously the classes below should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class CartItem
{
  public Product Product {get;set;}
  public int UnitsToBuy {get;set;}
  public int UnitsStep {get;set;}
  public decimal TotalPrice
  {
    get { return Product.Price * UnitsToBuy;}
  }
  //more properties can be added if needed
}

public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<CartItem> Products {get;set;}
}
```

and then in xaml you don't really need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new Model class that will contain what you need from Product and SubscribedProduct. You can then create a Mapper of sorts that will convert the more view-centric Model to your data-centric Model(s) (Product and SubscribedProduct).

Answer (score 0):

I always build my Views specifically for a Model or group of Models. Because of this, I know what properties to expect, and which ones may be missing.

If I know a property can be missing, I will write a `DataTrigger` to alter the view based on the data

For example, if I had a View that was supposed to be display `Products` and `SubscribedProducts`, I might use a `DataTrigger` to determine what DataTemplate to display

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DefaultProductTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type local:SubscribedProductModel}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SubscribedProductTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Don't think thats what i'm looking for, i'm not trying to display Products and Subscribed Products, i'm trying to display a Shopping list for products but the product it self is just its description not its "options" (how many units to buy). That doesn't seem to fit the binding mechanism for controls.

Comment: @GriffinHeart You'll need a different `Model` for that. Your product shouldn't be expected to track how many units to buy and the total price because that kind of data belongs to a `ProductOrder`, not a `Product`. You should create a `ProductOrder` class with a `Product`, `Amount`, and `TotalPrice`, which would be `Amount * Product.UnitPrice`.